# String Escape issue PHP

Tags: php, string

Hello I have following string in my variable

```
Hello@I am "good" too
```

I am using `mysql_real_escape_string()` when i am saving to database

So in database value saved as follows

```
Hello@I am \"good\" too
```

Now when I fetch this value back from database to input field (for updation purchase) like below

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo $edit_data['my_field'];?>">
```

it only shows `Hello@I am \`

What string escape function i should use?

I tried `stripslashes()` but then it only shows `Hello@I am`

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: Thats because your html element allready has double quotes.
value="<?php echo $edit_data['my_field'];?>"

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly will surely look at PDO, but right now my issue is with string (to show in input field again)

Comment: Yes i know @RFLdev but if i use single quote then there will be a issse when there is a single quote in string

Comment: "So in database value saved as follows" — The slashes are escape characters for the SQL statement. If they appear in the data you are getting out of the database than something is wrong.

Comment: did you try to just write your input without anyquote/double quote ? `<input type="text" name="field_name" value=<?php echo $edit_data['my_field'];?>>`

Comment: guys i got my answer, thanks @Quentin for redirecting me to helpful link, we can use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @A.Rossi — Then the first space would terminate the attribute value.